# I want to know the difference between FLAG_IMMUTABLE, FLAG_MUTABLE and FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT in pending intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I'm migrating my code to android 12 and I need to change pending intent flags
But I'm confused to choose where to use when

Please somebody suggest some articles or answer to this question.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can set many flags at once, Android 12 just forcing to use one of: `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` OR `FLAG_MUTABLE`, plus your desired. probably `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` should be also set for your intent, so if you are using "update current" feature then it should also have `FLAG_MUTABLE` (as `Intent` may be "updated")